# Can I configure how git detects merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-config

I have a tool that can compare and merge binary files. It can also try to automerge said binaries and aborts if there are changes that can not be decided on without humen intervention.
Is it possible to configure git to use my tool to detect if a merge leads to a merge conflict?

For example lets say it can deal with .png-files.
If I have two branches A and B and on branch A were changes to the pixel at `[150,100]` and on branch B were changes to the pixel at `[200, 50]`. If I now merge branch B into branch A my tool would detect that there are no conflicting changes and just automerge the image without raising a conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: you want a *merge driver*, which you declare for certain files in `.gitattributes`.  (The driver itself, you configure in `.git/config`.  See [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).)

You cannot configure how Git *decides* that some file needs to be merged.  The decision algorithm is far too simple for that, as it consists of:

1. Identify three files in the merge base commit and the the two sides (left and right, or ours and theirs).

   That is, suppose the merge base has a file named `path/to/abc.png` and the two sides also have files named `path/to/abc.png`.  Git assumes that all three names represent the *same* underlying file.

   If, say, the right (`--theirs`) side *doesn't* have `path/to/abc.png`, but *does* have `different/path/to/xyz.png` *and* that file seems to be newly created (doesn't exist in the merge base) *and* the contents of `xyz.png` are sufficiently similar to those of the base's `abc.png`, Git may choose to identify their `xyz.png` with the base's `abc.png` after all, but now the right side has a *name change* as well as a potential content difference.  This—renaming a file—is a *high level* change.

   Similarly, if one side *deletes the file entirely*, this is also a high level change.  (If both sides delete the file entirely, there's no problem here: the merge result is just "delete the file".)  The decision that one or both sides have deleted the file occurs because there's no *unmatched* file (such as this newly-created `xyz.png`) that looks sufficiently similar.
2. Now that we / Git have identified these three files as "the same", a non-trivial merge is required if *either of the following are true:*

   - Both the left and right sides changed the contents, to different contents.  That is, the blob hashes in the left and right side commits for the file differ *and* both are different from the base commit's blob hash.  Note that this does not yet mean that there is a *conflict!*  It just means that a merge is required.
   - Or, at least one side changed the content, *and* the other side made a *high level* change, such as renaming or deleting the file.  This is automatically a *high level conflict*.

If the conflict detected at this point is a *high level* conflict, Git *will* stop and get help.  However, it *may* first go on to invoke a *merge driver* on the three input files, if appropriate.

Putting any high level conflict or merge-requirement aside, Git now decides whether to invoke the *low level merge driver* on the three input files.  This happens if (and only if):

- there are in fact three files (none of the three are missing or deleted), and
- the blob hashes for all three differ.

The low-level merge driver is the one you configured through your `.gitattributes` file.  If you did not configure one through `.gitattributes`, it's either the built-in text file merge driver, or the built-in binary file merge driver.

The built-in text file merge driver tries to combine changes, using the usual diff-and-stick-merge-conflict-markers-in method.  If there's a conflict that the low level text merge driver cannot resolve, Git will stop and get help.

The built-in binary file merge driver just declares failure.  Git will stop and get help.

If you provide *your own* merge driver, *you* are responsible for producing the correct merge result and/or telling Git to stop and get help.  So if you have a merge driver that knows how to merge `.png` files, you may set that as your low level merge driver for `*.png`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you try to do a merge involving two PNG or other binary files, you will be at the mercy of Git's merge conflict detection algorithm.  This algorithm flags merge conflicts by changes in *text* files which involve differences within a certain proximity of each other (e.g. changes within several lines of each other).

While it is not impossible for you to use your binary merge tool in Git, you might have to do a custom build/fork of Git to make it happen.

In general, though, you should avoid versioning binary files in Git, because it does not handle binary content that well.